# How to get the xy position of a text in a QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to render a square containing the color when it's a hex color string, similar to the VSCode editor:

[image: 2ec4fa04-ae6f-4c2b-ac0c-1eb152811a14-Code_0G9nNbUtTh.gif]

When a valid hex string is entered it renders a "rectangle", you can click it and it modifies the hex string with the color selected in the widget.

In my attempt, I'm not figuring out how to move the cursor to the correct position and also check if it doesn't already contains a ■ after the hex string:

```
class HtmlHighlighter : public QSyntaxHighlighter
{
public:
    TextEdit* textEdit;
    QRegularExpression colorPattern = QRegularExpression("#[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}");
    HtmlHighlighter(TextEdit* parent) : QSyntaxHighlighter(parent), textEdit(parent) {}
    
protected:
    void highlightBlock(const QString& text) override
    {
        setCurrentBlockState(0);

        int startIndex = 0;
        if (previousBlockState() != 1)
            startIndex = text.indexOf(colorPattern);

        while (startIndex >= 0)
        {
            QRegularExpressionMatch match = colorPattern.match(text, startIndex);
            int endIndex = match.capturedStart();
            int colorLength = 0;

            if (endIndex == -1)
            {
                setCurrentBlockState(1);
                colorLength = text.length() - startIndex;
            }
            else
                colorLength = endIndex - startIndex + match.capturedLength();

            QString hexColor = match.captured(0);
            QColor color(hexColor);

            if (color.isValid())
            {
                QTextCharFormat colorFormat;
                colorFormat.setForeground(color);
                setFormat(startIndex, colorLength, colorFormat);

                startIndex = text.indexOf(colorPattern, startIndex + colorLength);

                qDebug() << "startIndex: " << startIndex << "endIndex:" << endIndex;
                QTextCursor cursor(document());
                cursor.setPosition(endIndex);
                cursor.insertHtml("<span style=\"color:" + color.name() + ";\">■</span>");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What are you trying to achieve from end user point of view? Maybe you need to just add some graphics into a QTextDocument?

Answer (score 0):

Have u figured out how to move cursor to correct position?

I use  `qtextedit::textChanged` signal

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <QFocusEvent>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSplitter>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QWebChannel>
#include <QPlainTextEdit>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSyntaxHighlighter>
#include <QRegularExpression>
#include <QTextCursor>
#include <QSvgRenderer>
#include <QPushButton>
using namespace std;

QTextCharFormat svgCharFormat;
class HtmlHighlighter;
HtmlHighlighter* htmlSyntax;
enum SvgProperties { SvgData = 1 };
enum { SvgTextFormat = QTextFormat::UserObject + 1 };

class SvgTextObject : public QObject, public QTextObjectInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
        Q_INTERFACES(QTextObjectInterface)
        //![1]

public:
    QSizeF intrinsicSize(QTextDocument* doc, int posInDocument,
        const QTextFormat& format) override;
    void drawObject(QPainter* painter, const QRectF& rect, QTextDocument* doc,
        int posInDocument, const QTextFormat& format) override;
};
class TextEdit :public QTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
        QRegularExpression hexColorPattern = QRegularExpression("#[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}\\b");
    const int colorLen = 7;
public:
    TextEdit(QWidget* parent) :QTextEdit(parent)
    {
        QObject* svgInterface = new SvgTextObject;
        svgInterface->setParent(this);
        document()->documentLayout()->registerHandler(SvgTextFormat, svgInterface);
        connect(this, &TextEdit::textChanged,this,&TextEdit::dohighlight);
    }
    void dohighlight()
    {
        disconnect(this, &TextEdit::textChanged,nullptr,nullptr );
        {
            QTextCursor newCursor(document());
            while (!newCursor.isNull() && !newCursor.atEnd())
            {
                newCursor = document()->find(hexColorPattern, newCursor);

                if (!newCursor.isNull())
                {
                    newCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::EndOfWord, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
                    QTextCharFormat colorFormat;
                    colorFormat.setForeground(QColor(newCursor.selectedText()));
                    newCursor.setCharFormat(colorFormat);

                    newCursor.clearSelection();
                    newCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Right, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, 1);
                    newCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Right, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor, 1);
                    QString str = newCursor.selectedText();
                    newCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Left, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, 1);
                    if (!(str.size() == 1 && str.at(0) == QChar::ObjectReplacementCharacter))
                    {
                        newCursor.insertText(QString(QChar::ObjectReplacementCharacter), svgCharFormat);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        {
            QTextCursor newCursor(document());
            while (!newCursor.isNull() && !newCursor.atEnd())
            {
                newCursor = document()->find(QString(QChar::ObjectReplacementCharacter), newCursor);
                if (!newCursor.isNull())
                {  
                    auto tmpCursor = newCursor;
                    tmpCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Left, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, 2);
                    tmpCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Left, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor, colorLen);
                    auto strtext= tmpCursor.selectedText();
                    QColor color(strtext);

                    if (color.isValid() && strtext.size() == colorLen)
                    {
                        ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newCursor.deleteChar();
                        QTextCharFormat colorFormat;
                        colorFormat.setForeground(Qt::black);
                        int posMove = 1;
                        for (;;posMove++)
                        {
                            auto cursorRun = newCursor;
                            cursorRun.movePosition(QTextCursor::Left, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor, posMove);
                            QString str = cursorRun.selectedText();
                            if (str.size() > colorLen|| str.indexOf(QChar::ObjectReplacementCharacter)!=-1)
                            {
                                auto cursorRun = newCursor;
                                cursorRun.movePosition(QTextCursor::Left, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor, posMove);
                                cursorRun.setCharFormat(colorFormat);
                                break;
                            }
                        }


                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        connect(this, &TextEdit::textChanged,this,&TextEdit::dohighlight);
    }
};

QSizeF SvgTextObject::intrinsicSize(QTextDocument* /*doc*/, int /*posInDocument*/,
    const QTextFormat& format)
{
    QImage bufferedImage = qvariant_cast<QImage>(format.property(SvgData));
    QSize size = bufferedImage.size();

    if (size.height() > 25)
        size *= 25.0 / (double)size.height();

    return QSizeF(size);
}
//![0]

//![1]
void SvgTextObject::drawObject(QPainter* painter, const QRectF& rect,
    QTextDocument* doc, int posInDocument,
    const QTextFormat& format)
{
    auto tp=format.objectType();
    QImage bufferedImage = qvariant_cast<QImage>(format.property(SvgData));

    painter->drawImage(rect, bufferedImage);

    QTextCharFormat colorFormat;
    colorFormat.setForeground(Qt::red);
    

    //htmlSyntax->rehighlight();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    int test = 0xfffc;
    QString fileName = "\\apis\\qt5.14.2\\Examples\\Qt-6.2.4\\svg\\richtext\\textobject\\files\\heart.svg";
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {

    }

    QByteArray svgData = file.readAll();
    svgCharFormat.setObjectType(SvgTextFormat);
    QSvgRenderer renderer(svgData);

    QImage svgBufferImage(renderer.defaultSize(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    QPainter painter(&svgBufferImage);
    renderer.render(&painter, svgBufferImage.rect());

    svgCharFormat.setProperty(SvgData, svgBufferImage);
    TextEdit* textEdit = new TextEdit(nullptr);
    
    textEdit->setText(R"(
      #ff0007   ddd
aa #ba00ff sdsd 7777777777777777777777777777  #00ff00 abbc #ba00ff dsafff32 #ba00ff 
#00ffb4 xxxx
    )");
    textEdit->show(); 
    //QPushButton pb;
    //QObject::connect(&pb, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]() {
    //htmlSyntax->rehighlight();});
    //pb.show();
    return a.exec();


}
#include"main.moc"
```